# Query return object by String Content

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I try to return Object by content which have string type:

```
public ObjectQuery<question> getQuestionByContent(String content)
{
    DemoDBEntities _context = new DemoDBEntities();
    var x = _context.question.Where(p => p.q_content == content);
    Debug.WriteLine(((ObjectQuery)x).ToTraceString());
    return (ObjectQuery<question>)x;
}
```

I call the function above by:

```
public question BS_GetQuestionByContent(String content)
{
    DB_Implementation _dal = new DB_Implementation();
    return _dal.getQuestionByContent(content).SingleOrDefault<question>();
}
```

and get:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: "An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
>   details."

important to note:
when I do this function whis Int Type String there is no problem.

any idea?

Comment: What is inner exception?

Comment: the inner exception: 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: In your database, what type is q_content?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ does not allow you to compare database fields with the text datatype using =.  For some ideas on what you can do about it, look at [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2586018/550062)